# Amazon driver left my package at the wrong address, can I retrieve it?

Tags: choshen-mishpat-civil-law

Amazon delivered my order to my Jewish neighbor's front porch. Until the item is on my property Amazon still owes me that item. [A person's property can be used for a kinyan.](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Kamma.64b?lang=bi) What are the limits of this rule? Is it possible for the item to halachicly belong to my neighbor by way of this law? Am I allowed to go get the package from his property, or does it now belong to my neighbor?

Comment: Since it is yours, just knock on your neighbors door and get it from him. That would also ensure that he knows that the correct person has received it.

Comment: The item does not belong to your neighbour because in order for a *kinyan* to occur there must be *daas makneh*, this means the person who owns the item must intend to convey ownership to you. In this case Amazon did not mean to convey ownership to your neighbour therefore it does not become theirs. It seems however that your neighbour would become a *shomer aveidah*, a guardian of a lost item, and therefore is responsible for the item and is obliged to return it to you as soon as they realise it has been left on their property in error.

Comment: If you just walk over to your neighbor’s property, and take the package, you might be thought of as a "porch pirate", which could land you in trouble. Even if you aren't charged, it doesn't look good, visually, and we're directed by the Torah not to do actions that will cause us to be suspected of wrongdoing.

Comment: @isrealreader they could ask their neighbour first